# Visualizing interpolation result with three js in QGis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, interpolation, qgis2threejs, three-js

I used topographic map to trace the contours in QGIS. For each line, I added an attribute value (ex. 565, 564, 563 etc). After that, I used the IDW and TIN interpolation methods to create a couple of DEM's from the contours. Finally, as I tried to visualize the result in 3D using threejs plugin, I get only flat terrain.

I'm using Balkan Zone 7 as CRS and I have only two attributes in my contour lines: "ID" and "Z" attribute as a whole number.

Any advice is welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this just now and it seems to work. See below. I've tried this with both float and integer rasters (QGIS 2.14.3, Plugin version 1.4).

I used gdal contour to generate the contours, though. In QGIS this is under **Raster > Extraction > Contour**. You might want to try that too.

[image: qgis2threejs rendering of dem interpolated from contours]

There's a few times this has happened to me, these are the things I usually get wrong:

- When you interpolate, make sure you choose the correct field for the 'interpolate attribute' (**`Z`** in your case). It may well have defaulted to **`ID`**. You can click on the raster using the 'Identify' tool to check that the raster values are what you expect.
- Make sure you have set the DEM layer under the 'DEM' tab in the plugin dialog. By default this isn't set and you'll get a flat rendering.
- Also check the 'vertical exaggeration' under the 'World' tab. You're using a CRS in meters, so make sure this value is 1.0 or similar. If you were working on a DEM whose CRS was in degrees before, this could be set to a very small value like 0.00001, which might be flattening your model.

If you get stuck, there's some [excellent documentation](http://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/) for this plugin.